# Renaming list items containing a dataframe, using the first entry of a column of the dataframe

Tags: r, list

I have data as follows:

```
dataset = list()
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(1,2,3)
country <- c("A","B","C")
source_country <-  c("D","D","D")
dataset[[1]] <- data.frame(a,b,country, source_country)
a <- c(NA)
b <- c(NA)
country <- c(NA)
source_country <- c(NA)
dataset[[2]] <- data.frame(a,b,country, source_country)
```

[image]

I want to rename each list item with the `source_country` from the data frame of the same list item. I tried the following:

```
for (i in 1:length(dataset)) {
   if (!is.null(dataset[[i]])) {
    print ("no data") 
  } else if (nrow(dataset[[i]]) > 1) {
    names(dataset)[i] <- dataset[[i]][["source_country"]][[1]]
  }   
}
```

But it does not seem to work..

Desired Outcome:

```
names(dataset)[1] <- "D"
names(dataset)[2] <- "NA"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your `R` version is less than 4.1.0 then replace `\(x)` with `function(x)`:

```
names(dataset) <- sapply(dataset, \(x) x$source_country[1])
```

This will give your second element a name of `NA`. If you want that to be a character you can wrap with the function `as.character`.

---

The problem with your loop is that you're testing if each element of your list is *not* null (`is.null` tests if the element is null, `!is.null` inverts this). Since each element of your list is a dataframe none of them are null so your loop never enters the `else if` clause. The only thing you're doing in your `if` statement is printing so nothing is renamed.

You could do something like:

```
for (i in 1:length(dataset)) {
  if (nrow(dataset[[i]]) == 0) {
    print ("no data") 
  } else if (nrow(dataset[[i]]) >= 1) {
    names(dataset)[i] <- dataset[[i]][["source_country"]][1]
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr` option -

```
library(purrr)

set_names(dataset, map_chr(dataset, pluck, "source_country", 1))

#$D
#  a b country source_country
#1 1 1       A              D
#2 2 2       B              D
#3 3 3       C              D

#$<NA>
#   a  b country source_country
#1 NA NA      NA             NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
setNames(dataset,   unlist(sapply(dataset, subset, 
   subset = seq_along(source_country) == 1, select = source_country)))
```

-ouptut

```
$D
  a b country source_country
1 1 1       A              D
2 2 2       B              D
3 3 3       C              D

$<NA>
   a  b country source_country
1 NA NA      NA             NA
```